# NoMethodError in Student#categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Showing `/home/ns/school/app/views/student/_student_category_list.erb` where line #4 raised:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

```
<ul id="category-list">


            <% @student_categories.each do |c| %>

                <li class="list<%=cycle('odd', 'even')%>">
                    <div class="category-name"><%= c.name %></div>
                    <div class="category-edit"><%= link_to "#{t('edit_text')}", :url => { :action => 'category_edit', :id => c.id } %> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-delete"><%= link_to  "#{t('delete_text')}", :url => { :action => 'category_delete', :id => c.id } , :confirm =>"#{t('delete_confirm_msg')}"%>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <% end %>

    </ul>
```

Comment: `@student_categories` is nil, exactly as the error says.

Comment: what is you controller's action which is rendering this ?

Comment: Please post your controller code

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, everyone needs too see your controller code, because they want to ensure that the instance variable @student_categories contains a hash of your data.

However, we can all infer that @student_categories is either:

1. Not being initialized in the controller at all, which would result in your error.
2. Not being initialized in the correct controller action.
3. Is being misspelled as @student_category/@student_categories someplace in your code, (rails pluralization can be confusing at first.)

*Solution:*

- Check that your model is named **student_category.rb** or **student.rb**
- Check that your controller is named **student_categories_controller.rb** or **students.rb**

Since you are listing all of your categories, I'm going to assume that your @student_categories variable is to be found in your index action, within the **student_categories_controller.rb** *In your case this would be the student_category_list action.*

Adjust appropriately.

```
class StudentCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def student_categories_list
    # Some Action  
  end
end
```

You should have an index action in your controller, like this:

```
def index
  @student_categories = StudentCategory.all # Not good for production
end
```

Or maybe, it looks like this:

```
def index
  @student_category = StudentCategory.all # Not good for production
end
```

Perhaps it even looks like this:

```
def index
  @student_categories = Student.all # Not good for production
end
```

With your model, view, and controller code, we could give you an exact solution, but 99% of the time it's a problem with pluralization. Rails has some naming [conventions you should look at.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

*Also, be careful using Model.all in production,  since there could be tens of thousands of records in a model.*

Answer (score 0):

This mean that @student_categories is not initialized or has a nil value. Have a look to your controller to be sure that the initialization is done.